# Firestore onSnapshot returning wrong timestamp format

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I get FireStore document using `.get()` my time field returns this value: `createdAt: "2018-12-25T01:04:05.189Z"` but when I use `onSnapshot`, time field returns different value:

**1)** using `onSnapshot`:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.ref.doc('HCNFO3ZKlFNKK71JMzo8').onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    this.setState({
      theLocation: querySnapshot.data()
    })
  }
```

returns: `mylocations: {
   createdAt: Timestamp {seconds: 1545723905, nanoseconds: 177000000}
}`

**2)** on the cloud functions using `.get()`

```
.then(() => {
  return firebaseAdminSDK.firestore().collection('locations').doc('HCNFO3ZKlFNKK71JMzo8').get()
})
```

returns: `mylocations: {
   createdAt: "2018-12-25T07:45:05.177Z"
}`

when saving location I used `data.createdAt = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();` on the cloud functions

Any idea whats going on?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code in both cases.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, I added more details

Comment: I think you mean it's a difference between admin sdk in cloud functions and javascript sdk in your client app rather than difference between `get` and `onSanpshot`. I think using get in your client app has the same result as onSanpshout for timestamps.

Comment: I don't see the code where you're actually printing or attempting to deal with the vaules.  Please, no screenshots - they are not helpful.  Copy the text directly into the question.

Comment: Those values are the same time though, just in different representations.  Is there actually an issue here?  `1545723905` in seconds since Epoch is `December 25, 2018 7:45:05`, which is the value the other method returned, so they're both giving the same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using `moment.utc()` on cloud functions.

Replaced `const createdAt = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` with `const createdAt = moment.utc().valueOf()`

After that `createdAt` field returns same value on both cloud functions & frontend fetch, because its stores timestamp as `number` instead of `timestamp` in the firestore.

Comment: You have replaced the timestamp of when the data is created in database with the timestamp of when the function is called. There's a subtle difference and it has a different meaning. Specially if you do the same on frontend.

Answer (score 1):

The new `Timestamp` object, with seconds and nanoseconds, in javascript client library is gonna be the default timestamp which will replace the old javascript `Date` objects in firebase timestamps. You should adopt the new behavior and update your code to use the new timestamp objects.

To get the Date object from the timestamp use `toDate()` method:

```
const timestamp = snapshot.get('createdAt');
const date = timestamp.toDate();
```

You can make the new timestamp behavior the default behavior in you app and cloud functions and update your code so that when the Date objects are removed your app doesn't break. To use the new timestamp you can add `timestampsInSnapshots: true` to Firestore settings:

```
// javascript sdk
firebase.firestore().settings({
   /* other settings */
   timestampsInSnapshots: true
})

// admin sdk
admin.firestore().settings({
   /* other settings */
   timestampsInSnapshots: true
})
```

Comment: UPDATE: 'timestampsInSnapshots: true' is being deprecated by Google... REF: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Settings